# Jquery Datatables : Getting data from server

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Jquery datatable sAjaxSource is not getting the data from server.but when I using .getJSON method , its getting from server.So why this method is not working in datatable ?

```
$(document).ready( function () {

$('#table_id').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "ajax/sayHi.action"
          } );
} );
```

but my action class is returning the data for below jquery code.

```
$(function(){
$("#introForm").submit(function(){       
var formInput=$(this).serialize();       
$.getJSON('ajax/sayHi.action', formInput,function(data) { 
---------------------
}

{"countryList":["US","UK","Russia"],"countryMap":{"US":1,"UK":2,"Russia":3},"greeting":"HI 1","name":"1"}
```

I want to get the data in datatable, Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, datatables requires a particular form of json string to be returned from the server. The string should consist of:

```
iTotalRecords (int)
iDisplayRecords (int)
sEcho (string)
aaData (array)
```

see here: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side (check "reply from the server")